# How to add two or more variables in jQuery ( mirror of .= operator in PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry i am so new to jQuery and not sure how to do that.

Basically in php i can do something like this:

```
$result = '';
$result .= 'Hi';
$result .= ' there';
echo $result;
```

I am just asking if there's an exact copy or alternative in jQuery. instead of adding variables with plus sign which works for me, but I want all variables to be added up to the large variable, just i do in php.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just a note, a more specific way to say describe this operation is 'to concatenate two strings'.

Comment: you must realize that this is string concatenation in javascript and not just for jquery. The answers here are applicable to javascript anywhere: whether in a browser or in some standalone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, yes, + is used for concatenation, but is the equivalent of `.` in PHP. The direct equivalent of `.=` in JavaScript is `+=`

```
var $result = '';
$result += 'Hi';
$result += ' there';
alert($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I was trying to find the direct equivalent which does not let me create more variables then concatenate all of them later. Vote up merci :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = '';
result += 'Hi';
result += ' there';
document.write(result);
```

Note this is just plain javascript, not jquery

Comment: @Ahmad Fouad Yes. jQuery is written with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is the dual purpose `+` operator.

Though it won't be your friend for long when you realise overloading the addition operator for string concatenation can bite you bad in a dynamically typed language.

There is also a jQuery plugin (seeing as you tagged it jQuery) :P.

```
jQuery.strcat = function() {  
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join();
};

alert($.strcat('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

## ☺

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the [concatenation operator](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp) is '+':

```
var str = 'Hello' + ' ' + 'Fred';
alert(str);
```

You can't interpolate variables in a double-quoted string, as you can with PHP (which is one of the purposes of PHP's dollar ($) [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29)). You have to use concatenation:

```
var anotherStr = str + ', what day is it?';
// or
str += ', what day is it?';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the + operator for string concatenation, as described above.

Worth mentioning is another way to do this. Put the items into an array, and use the `join` method. This is common in Python and other language.

```
result=[];
result.push('Hi');
result.push('there');
result.join(' ');
```

Comment: which is more effective as per performance , push or + , push is like a array push right.

Comment: @gov `push()` and `join()` is, though I don't think the performance outweighs the readability suffering (unless you are appending hundreds of strings).